# Contrario di esplicitezza - sostantivo

Tags: nouns

Salve a tutti. Qual è il contrario di esplicitezza? Facendo una ricerca sembra che non esista.

Grazie anticipatamente.

Comment: Forse "ermetico" può essere un contrario.

Comment: Sul Dizionario Treccani online non ho trovato "implicitezza", presente in altri Dizionari e anche nel Treccani, usato in varie voci (http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/tag/implicitezza/)

Comment: Ciao @Benedetta. Per favore potresti indicarmi su quale dizionario hai trovato il termine implicitezza?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi: Hoepli (http://www.grandidizionari.it/Dizionario_Italiano/parola/I/implicitezza.aspx), De Mauro (https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/implicitezza).

Comment: Grazie molte @Benedetta.

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi prego, figurati.

Comment: @Benedetta: Potresti scrivere quello che hai trovato come risposta?

Comment: @Charo: lo faccio subito!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sul Dizionario Treccani online non ho trovato "implicitezza", termine che è però presente in altri Dizionari (Hoepli: http://www.grandidizionari.it/Dizionario_Italiano/parola/I/implicitezza.aspx; De Mauro: https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/implicitezza).

Nell'Enciclopedia Treccani, però, il termine è usato in varie voci (http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/tag/implicitezza/).

Comment: @Charo: Grazie della correzione, stavo per farla! :-)